# How to use Laravel facades (Cache, Log, Storage) in package outside Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dependencies, composer-php, phpunit

Please point out any naivete or incorrect assumptions I'm making about Laravel, Composer, PHPUnit, etc.

I had a class called SpeechToTextHelper that was inside a Laravel project, and it used facades like this:

```
use Cache;
use Log;
use Storage;
```

Then, since I wanted to share it between multiple Laravel projects, I moved it into a separate repo and required it (into the first project) as a dependency via Composer.

The code all seems to run fine.

My question is different from [Using Laravel Facades outside Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722677/using-laravel-facades-outside-laravel)

What I want to know is:

1. Now that I also want to write PHPUnit tests for SpeechToTextHelper in my new tools repo, I see errors like `RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.` and `Error: Class 'Log' not found`, presumably because this tools repo has no awareness of Laravel. I guess this means my production code has been working just by side-effect.
2. In my new tools repo (where my SpeechToTextHelper now is), how am I supposed to indicate (maybe somewhere in composer.json?) that the code will only work if Laravel's facades exist and are initiated properly?

How can I fix my separate repo's code so that its tests can run and also so that it ensures that it can only be "required" by a Laravel project?

P.S. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades says "When building a third-party package that interacts with Laravel, it's better to inject Laravel contracts (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/contracts) [which live in their own GitHub repository] instead of using facades." "If you are building a package, you should strongly consider using contracts since they will be easier to test in a package context."

But I do not see contracts for Log or Storage at all.

Comment: instead using `Log::debug` can we try as `app('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log')::debug`  ?

Comment: @phpdroid I get "A facade root has not been set." I'm actually confused about how `app()` exists at all; I don't see where/how that gets defined in this side project. But Xdebug does show that `app()` gets called, but then it throws that RuntimeException.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Laravel component repositories

1. Cache - This [component](https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/tree/master/components/cache) shows how to use Laravel's Cache features in non-Laravel applications.
2. Log - This [component](https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/tree/master/components/log) shows how to use Laravel's Log features in non-Laravel applications.

This [video](https://laracasts.com/lessons/how-to-use-eloquent-outside-of-laravel) shows, how you can use eloquent outside laravel, I think that will give you better idea.

Comment: That's interesting and felt like it was on the right track but doesn't answer either of my questions. E.g. https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/blob/master/components/log/index.php doesn't use the Log facade. And it's not clear to me what `$app = new \Slim\App();` means or how I would use that in my PHPUnit tests to make them work with my `Log::debug` calls.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not positive that this is the best approach, so I'd love if others
>   would provide better answers.

**For production code**

My `composer.json` still has this in the "require" section: `"laravel/framework": "5.7.*",`.

I plan to only ever require *this* tools library from within a Laravel app. I'm not *sure* that this is the right way to make that a *rule*, but my production code at least seems to be working.

**For tests**

As for tests, what seems to have been necessary was to add these files from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/2a1f3761e89df690190e9f50a6b4ac5ebb8b35a3:

```
app/Console/Kernel.php
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php
app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
bootstrap/cache/.gitignore
bootstrap/app.php
bootstrap/autoload.php
config/app.php
config/database.php
config/logging.php
config/view.php
storage/logs/laravel.log
tests/CreatesApplication.php
tests/TestCase.php
```

Perhaps those are the minimum set of barebones Laravel files without which tests can't run.

Then I made sure that each test class extended `tests/TestCase.php`. And I adjusted the namespaces.